# Find the orthogonal projection of vector $x$ on the space of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the orthogonal projection of vector $x$ on the space of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$.

> $ x = [4,-1,-3,4]^T, a_3 = [1,0,0,3]^T , a_2 = [1,2,2,-1]^T , a_3 = [1,1,1,1]^T$

Well, $x,a_1,a_2,a_3$ are given in the question. I want to ask how can I approach this question.

1. I use that $P_{Col(A)}x = Ax$ and it is really straight forward.
2. I'm not sure how to implement this but, I do know that every space/subspace has a basis, I check if the given matrix $A$ columns are linearly independent. and if yes, I somehow need to continue from there. maybe Make this basis orthonormal and somehow use fourier coeffcients.

Comment: Is there a mistake? The $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ are linealy dependent.

Comment: Fourier coefficients??? I don't see any exponential or trigonometric functions here...

Comment: @Marc van Leeuwen, Fourier coefficients refer to $\langle x, e_i\rangle$ where $\{e_i\}$ is orthonormed basis in Hilbert space. Trigonometric functions are just a particular case.

Comment: Note that $a_1+a_2=2a_3$: your vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduce an orthonormal basis for the subspace first. Then use the standard inner product:
$$p_{\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle}(x)=\langle x, a_1\rangle a_1 +\langle x, a_2\rangle a_2 +\langle x, a_3\rangle a_3.$$

Comment: Bernard, do $a_1,a_2,a_3$ need to form an orthonormal basis before I can use what you wrote? or just be linearly independent? (in other words, do $a_1$ has to be a normalized vector so I can use the formula u wrote

Comment: Oh! Yes, I forgot to mention that point. You have to deduce an orthonormal basis from the system of generators first.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can use Gram-Schmidt process on your vectors $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and then find coefficients $\langle x,e_i\rangle$ where $\{e_i\}_i$ is orthonormed basis for $\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$.

Comment: Ennar, what about $Ax = p$? will it work?

Comment: Yes, by the uniqueness property of any basis. You will have explicit decomposition of $x = a + b$ where $a\in\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ and $b\in\operatorname{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}^\perp$.